# How to solve this litle problem in React Native? ";" expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, syntax-error

I'm beginner in programming so dont laugh at me, can you please help me with this? Why it gets error what is the problem here?
P.S I know that problem is me, but anyway..
Look at the screenshot
[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKyGS.png)

[image: second part]

Comment: SearchScreen is a functional component, not a class component. Because it's a function you can't use class structures.

Comment: Don't post images of code, post it as rext, with the proper formating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell because the top of the component is not included in your screenshot *(See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))*

However it looks like you have a functional component that you are trying to treat like a class based component.

---

If this is a functional component you probably declare state with the use state hook. To do that right would look something like:

```
const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState('')
```

And then the component becomes something like:

```
export function SearchScreen() {
  const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState("");
  
  const filterData = DATA.filter((item) => {
    item.title.includes(searchKey)
  }) // removed the comma here

  return <SafeAreaView>...jsx here...</SafeAreaView>
};
```

---

If this is a class based component, then you want something like:

```
class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { searchKey: '' }
  }

  render() {
    const filterData = DATA.filter((item) => {
      item.title.includes(this.state.searchKey)
    }) // removed the comma here

    return <SafeAreaView>...jsx here...</SafeAreaView>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've written so far would be equivalent to

```
const SearchScreen = ({navigator}) => {
  const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState("");

  const renderItem = ...
};
```

Comment: ok i think I understand but , what should I write in OnChange options? I added a second screenshot please take a look

Comment: useState returns a setter function, in this case `setSearchKey`. Check out the React docs for useState.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the community. It's good to see your courage asking for solution. Regarding the problem you are facing, one thing is very much important to and that is the different of class based component and functional based component. Here is the link can help out:

**Differences between Functional Components and Class Components in React:**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react

Now after reading the article (mentioned above), have you found the solution?

Try this (thank me later):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class SearchScreen extends React.Component{

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        searchKey : "",
    };
}
```

Be sure to make this component as class based component thoroughly.

As a beginner, I'd recommend learn function based components, the basics of OOP (Object oriented programming) and the functionalities of "this" keyword. And yes, keep this courage all the time.

Comment: I would _strongly_ disagree that beginners should use class based components. Class components are a legacy feature that is supported for compatibility with older codebases. Functional components and hooks are the current recommended approach for creating react apps and a beginner should start with the current best practices in any new technology.

Comment: I strongly agree with you but nowadays, some novice (pure fresher) developers don't want to learn the basics of OOP (at least) but jump hurry to learn react-native after investing say 1 week (only) in learning ReactJS. In that perspective, my recommendation was mentioned. Nevertheless, I do agree with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I just worry about other beginner developers finding this answer and then learning legacy React patterns. React class based components are a pretty poor place to learn OOP principles, and modern React is much more functional in nature. So I believe this recommendation could be harmful to people that are at a very impressionable part of their programming journey.

Comment: Agreed, edited the recommendation.